# Continuously run code while UI button pressed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a **platform game** in Unity, where the ball is moved with **three buttons**:

- ***move right***
- ***move left***
- ***jump***

I already have all the functions that work now, but to move the character **i need to keep spamming a button, instead of holding it as i would want to**. I have tried a few ways I found on tutorials but, as i am still a very beginner, i did not manage to make them work.

This is the code of my ***Move2D*** script attatched to the character:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Move2D : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;
    public bool isGrounded = false;

    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rigidbody;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (!rigidbody) rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    public void Jump()
    {
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector3(0f, 5f), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }

    public void Move(float value)
    {
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(value, 0f, 0f);
        transform.position += movement * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
    }
}
```

And this is the ***second*** script that mainly controls all the movement:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ContinuesButton : MonoBehaviour, IPointerExitHandler, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    [SerializeField] private Button button;

    [SerializeField] private UnityEvent whilePressed;

    private readonly bool isHover;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (!button) button = GetComponent<Button>();
    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        StartCoroutine(WhilePressed());
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();
    }

    private IEnumerator WhilePressed()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            whilePressed?.Invoke();
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Any information or explanations is really appreciated as this part is very important for my game! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your player has a rigidbody, you can move the player via the rigidbody's velocity rather than through it's transform.
(This makes it more consistent too, since your jump's implementation uses rigidbody)

Velocity is made out of `Direction` and `Speed`; Since speed is constant, You can make the button set the direction of the movement.
And since you would want the player to hold down the button in order to move, you can set the direction of the movement `OnPointerDown`, and reset it when `OnPointerUp` occurs, like so:

#### Move2D.cs

```
public class Move2D : MonoBehaviour {
    // ...

    [SerializeField]
    private float speed;

    private Rigidbody2D rigidBody;

    private Vector2 currentMoveDirection;

    private void Awake() {
        rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        currentMoveDirection = Vector2.zero;
    }

    // ...

    private void FixedUpdate() {
        rigidBody.velocity = (currentMoveDirection + new Vector2(0f, rigidBody.velocity.y)).normalized * speed;
    }

    public void TriggerMoveLeft() {
        currentMoveDirection += Vector2.left;
    }

    public void StopMoveLeft() {
        currentMoveDirection -= Vector2.left;
    }

    public void TriggerMoveRight() {
        currentMoveDirection += Vector2.right;
    }

    public void StopMoveRight() {
        currentMoveDirection -= Vector2.right;
    }
}
```

#### PlayerMoveButton.cs

(Or your `ContinuesButton.cs`)

```
public class PlayerMoveButton : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler {
    [SerializeField]
    private Button targetButton;

    [SerializeField, Tooltip("The targeted player's movement component")]
    private Move2D playerMovement;

    [SerializeField, Tooltip("True if this button moves the player to the left")]
    private bool movesLeft;

    // ...

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData) {
        if (movesLeft) {
            playerMovement.TriggerMoveLeft();
        } else {
            playerMovement.TriggerMoveRight();
        }
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData) {
        if (movesLeft) {
            playerMovement.StopMoveLeft();
        } else {
            playerMovement.StopMoveRight();
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

> `LeftButton` is now clicked (`OnPointerDown`), `currentMoveDirection` is set to `Left (-1, 0)`.
>  The moment the button is let go (`OnPointerUp`), the `currentMoveDirection` is reset to normal `(0, 0)`
>
> The player constantly moves by setting it's velocity via `currentMoveDirection * speed`

#### Edit

And in order to preserve the `jump` motion, rather than simply do `currentMoveDirection * speed`, you would need to add the current upwards direction to it, like so:

```
private void FixedUpdate() {
    rigidBody.velocity = (currentMoveDirection + new Vector2(0f, rigidBody.velocity.y)).normalized * speed;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But now it produced two problems. The ball cannot jump anymore by clicking the Jump button, and there is a very strange and low gravity. I did not change the gravity scale (which is set to 1) and the ball is moving down very very slowly. How do i solve those two problems? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @EnricoCortinovis My fault in not taking account of the jumping motion; Edited my answer, hopefully it works since I am currently not able to test it.

Comment: I left the jump() function as it was before in my code, and changed the FixedUpdate(), but the compiler indicates that i cannot add a vector2D and a float. (And should i modify something in Jump() or only in the fixedUpdate?) Thank you very much!

Comment: @EnricoCortinovis Edited again; I was trying to add the current upward motion to `currentMoveDirection`, so it should be `new Vector2(0f, rigidBody.velocity.y)`

Comment: The gravity is back normal now. There is a new problem: now, it looks like when the ball goes up for any reasons (following the platform or jumping) it keeps going up, and I don't think it would stop afterwards. How could we fix this?

Comment: Try toggling around the rigidybodies settings? If it doesnt work, you can manually apply gravity like so: `(new Vector2(0f, rigidBody.velocity.y) * 9.8f * Time.fixedDeltaTime)`; It will apply a gravityScale of `9.8f`.

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't think there is any problem in the gravity there. If i move the ball right and left or down (because of the gravity) it works fine. If I press jump it starts going up. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @EnricoCortinovis `9.8` should be a negative value, hence `-9.8f`; Since gravity applies negatively on the Y axis

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199496/discussion-between-enrico-cortinovis-and-kaynn).