# I want to make my unity gun script for vr be automatic, any way to do it with this script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want it so that if my player holds down the fire button, the gun will be automatic firing so that if I hold the trigger the gun will keep shooting, any way to do that (with fire rate) with this script?
On my image the top is my XR grab interactable.
The button I use to fire is my trigger.
[XR grab interactable on top, gun script on bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFYli.png)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Gun : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 40;
    public GameObject bullet;
    public Transform barrel;
    public AudioSource audioSource;
    public AudioClip audioClip;

    public void Fire()
    {
        GameObject spawnedBullet = Instantiate(bullet, barrel.position, barrel.rotation);
        spawnedBullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = speed * barrel.forward;
        audioSource.PlayOneShot(audioClip);
        Destroy(spawnedBullet, 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us where exactly you call the `Fire` from? Is it a UI.Button?

Comment: See e.g. [Continuously run code while UI button pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57941225/continuously-run-code-while-ui-button-pressed) and similar questions

Comment: Ok, I added an image of where I call it from, which is an XR grab interactable. I put the gun script in my base model of my gun, along with my rigidbody, xr grab interactable etc

Answer (score 1):

In your case you already have to events: `OnActivate` and `OnDeactivate` so you could modify your code like this

```
public class Gun : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 40;
    public GameObject bullet;
    public Transform barrel;
    public AudioSource audioSource;
    public AudioClip audioClip;

    // configure shots per second
    public float rate = 1;

    private Coroutine _current;

    public void BeginFire()
    {
        if(_current != null) StopCoroutine(_current);

        _current = StartCoroutine (FireRoutine ());
    }

    public void StopFire()
    {
        if(_current != null) StopCoroutine(_current);
    }

    private IEnumerator FireRoutine()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            GameObject spawnedBullet = Instantiate(bullet, barrel.position, barrel.rotation);
            spawnedBullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = speed * barrel.forward;
            audioSource.PlayOneShot(audioClip);
            Destroy(spawnedBullet, 2);

            yield return new WaitForSeconds (1f / rate);
        }
    }
}
```

And then as so far in `OnActivate` call the `BeginFire` and in the `OnDeactivate` call the `StopFire`